# Aggregate data from multiple studies, to build a prediction model

Tags: probability, correlation, classification, statistical-significance, odds-ratio

- There are $20$ studies, each with different $n$.
- Individuals analysed all have concrete (non-speculative) susceptibility numbers

### How do I combine all the studies into one model?

Goal is to [speculatively] predict the susceptibility of these new individuals, given a less complete/professional examination (e.g.: a survey rather than a study using objective instruments).

Previously the plan was to multiply the [odds ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio) from each study together, but not sure if that approach is sound.

Comment: If you could provide more info this question would be easier to answer. We need clear understanding of structure of data as well as nature of problem...  Structure/type of your data in each study? Definition of susceptibility? Range in n-values? Individuals covered in multiple studies within dataset?

Comment: Tabular data that is aggregated into categories. Categories are equivalent between studies. Aggregated as in no individual data. Each study can be seen as independent, with no overlap of individuals surveyed. Median n of 2500.

Comment: To  clarify, do you have disaggregate data (on individual level) from 20 studies and you want to build one regression model or do you have model estimates from 20 studies that you want to combine?

Comment: @tomka: I don't have any of the individual [disaggregated] data, although I'm trying to acquire it. In the meantime I'm seeking some way of combining the aggregated data across studies of different sizes and longitudinal depth.